# getting unpocessed php from httpservics as result FB4

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex, flash-builder, httpservice

Hello pleassse help am using httpservice in flash builder 4 for a login system, but am getting the result as raw php unprocessed data from server, but when i run the same file in the browser i get a correct xml file am using MAMP, 
PLEASE HELP donno what's the problem here is the php code :

```
    <?php

define( "DATABASE_SERVER", "localhost:8888" );
  define( "DATABASE_USERNAME", "root" );
  define( "DATABASE_PASSWORD", "root" );
  define( "DATABASE_NAME", "touch" );

//connect to the database
  $mysql = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

//select the database
  mysql_select_db( DATABASE_NAME );

//These are the variables that Flex is passing to PHP
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
  $logincookie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["logincookie"]);

//Check the credentials
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
  $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

//Output the returned query in XML: If returned false output 0 else output the users id
$output = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
  $output .= "<loginsuccess>";
  if(!$result)
  {
  $output .= $username;
  }else{
  $output .= $username;
  }
  $output .= "</loginsuccess>";

//Output the User Type
  $usrtyp .= "<usertype>";
  $usrtyp .= $result['user_type'];
  $usrtyp .= "</usertype>";

//output all the XML

print ($output);
  print ($usrtyp);

?>
```

and here is the request :

```
<s:HTTPService id="login_user" result="checkLogin(event)" showBusyCursor="true" method="POST"
                   url="login.php" useProxy="false">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <username>
                {username.text}
            </username>
            <password>
                {password.text}
            </password>
        </s:request>
    </s:HTTPService>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with a wild guess that you're not running this off of an HTTP server, but just referencing to the html/swf file itself on your filesystem, hence the PHP is not being processed.

Comment: yeah right it was a web app and i turned it to windows app  that's why i didn't reference the full address of the login.php file :D